# Excel Macro For Data Analysis

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building a spreadsheet macro that copies cells from one spreadsheet called DATA to a tab called REPORT based on criteria. If the criteria changes, the list clears and it adds the values that meet the new criteria. The macro is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("B2:C5")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) _
           Is Nothing Then
           For iRow = 2 To 5845
        If Worksheets("DATA").Range("F" & iRow).Value = False Then
        'Do nothing
        Else
            Worksheets("WORK").Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Worksheets("DATA").Cells(iRow, 4).Value
        End If
    Next iRow
    End If
     Call Worksheets("WORK").Delete_Blank_Rows
     Sheets("REPORT").Range("E1:E5845").Value = Sheets("WORK").Range("A1:A5845").Value
     Worksheets("REPORT").Columns(6).ClearContents
End Sub

Sub Delete_Blank_Rows()
  On Error Resume Next
  With Worksheets("WORK").Range("A2:A5845")
    .Value = .Value
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
  End With
End Sub
```

The spreadsheet is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G-RQ9DvGKa_EEapcLIWDf3_SCdql_dJJ/view?usp=sharing

The error I receive is

> runtime error saying object doesn't support property or method.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which is the line triggering the error?

Comment: What's with the `.Value = .Value`?

Comment: Worksheets("REPORT").Range("E1:E5845").Value = Worksheets("WORK").Range("A1:A5845").Value

Comment: I'm not sure what the .Value is for. The guy that helped with this basically has the macro copy the data that meets the requirements to a sheet called WORK, then remove all the blanks from it, then copies that data to the REPORT worksheet

Comment: The Macro is now staying "out of stack space"

Comment: Also, why in your line: `Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address))` are you  using the `.Address` property just to convert it back to a range? All you need is: `Intersect(KeyCells, Target)` as `Target` is already a **Range Object**.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is suspicious. I suspect that it is hiding an error which affects the calling code.

Comment: I updated the code - it's using the Target without the .Address

Comment: The code still does not work. I updated the .Address just to show the new code since it wasn't actually related to the problem.

Comment: The new error is "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' Failed

Answer (score 0):

Your `Call` method of your worksheet object appears to be causing the issue.

You are attempting to call a **SUB** by using it as a child object of a worksheet:

```
Call Worksheets("WORK").Delete_Blank_Rows
```

needs to be changed to

```
Delete_Blank_Rows
```

---

Also, remove the `Call` keyword. You don't need it.

> ## [Call Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/call-statement)
>
> You can use the `Call` keyword when you call a procedure. For most procedure calls, you aren’t required to use this keyword.
>
> You typically use the `Call` keyword when the called expression doesn’t start with an identifier. Use of the `Call` keyword for other uses **isn’t recommended**.